# Defining a struct within a separate executable evidence file

Tags: c, struct, typedef, program-entry-point, void

I keep trying to compile my separate executable file for all of my tests, and get this error:
"variable has incomplete type 'struct observations', 'struct preferences', 'struct climate'"?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "file4.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

void eanalyze_weather()
{
  struct observations day1;
  day1.temp = 70.0;
  day1.humid = 30.0;
  day1.wind = 5.0;

  struct observations day2;
  day2.temp = 74.0;
  day2.humid = 24.0;
  day2.wind = 0.0;

  struct observations day3;
  day3.temp = 84.0;
  day3.humid = 18.0;
  day3.wind = 10.0;

int main(void)
{

  econcat();
  euint_to_binary();
  ebinary_to_uint();
  eanalyze_weather();
  return 0;
}
```

When I try to run everything in "main" in a single file, it compiles properly and the code works, but when I try to do it this way, it is not compiling. Does anyone know why this is?

Thank you.

Comment: where is `struct observations` defined?

Comment: I defined it in my other file

Comment: what other file? in `file4.h`? show your compilation statement, show your files and more importantly, copy the exact error message.

Comment: when I try to compile it all in one file, it works perfectly, but I'm testing out running this on a 2nd file aside from all of my definitions, just to solidify my understanding of concepts...

Comment: no, in my file4.c. 
This is my file4_evidence.c

Answer (score 0):

This error is because the definition of `struct observations` is not visible from the file containing `main()`, since the definition in present in some other file [separate translation unit].

One workaround (and the usual best practice) is to put the definition of the structure in the header file and don't forget to include some [include guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

Comment: Thank you, I've figured it out!

Comment: Also, is there a reason why I am getting a seg fault when I try to run this now?
Do I have to allocate memory to list[]?

Comment: @LeehoLim how can i tell my friend without seeing your full code? and BTW, that is supposed to be a new question altogether, IMO.

Comment: Well I know the issue is not with the file where I define my functions (because I have tested everything...)
So I am assuming the error is with this file4_evidence.c file that I have posted

Comment: @LeehoLim apparently all is fine in this code. You got to have some issue in other files.